# Place Anchor Tag inside JQuery JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

i have jquery syntax to consume json list from database.

here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //function to get the result from user-input
    $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
        $("#posting").html("");
        //show the div section
        $("#divContent").show("slow", function(){
            //getting value from searchbox
            valobj = $('#search_box').val();
            //execute data from database.
            $.getJSON("search.php", { q : valobj }, function(data,result){
                //show result from database
                $.each(data.content, function(index, value) { 
                    var li = $("<li><h3></h3><p></p></li>");
                    $("#posting").append(li);
                    $("h3",li).text("<a href='post.php?id='>" + value.title + "</a>");
                    $("p",li).text(value.intro_text);           
                });  
                //end show result
            }, JSON);

        }); //end show div section

    }); //end click function
```

As you can see above, i need to place anchor to post title, so when user click it, it will redirect to another page

```
  $("h3",li).text("<a href='post.php?id='>" + value.title + "</a>");
```

But it is not working and shows a result to browser example: Test Post 100

how to properly insert anchor on the jquery function?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `$(element).html(" HTML content here")` instead of `text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.html()`

```
$("h3",li).html("<a href='post.php?id='>" + value.title + "</a>");
```

From the API :

> We need to be aware that this method (*`.text()`*) escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as
>   HTML

- http://api.jquery.com/text/
- http://api.jquery.com/html/